# Open Graph Story disappears

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm creating open graph story on facebook from a website registered as an APP in Facebook. 
However, after the story is created, around 5min, the story disappears from both users that are connected in the story.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the code you've used?

Answer (score 0):

It disappeared for me too. Although after 15-30 mins. I am assuming there is quick purging for apps in development? Few days back, i was able to see the story that was posted by the same app 2 weeks ago!

Answer (score 0):

I got this very same problem at the moment. But yes, I agree with srilesnar, it is probably to keep things clean, and to keep FBs servers from using unnecessary HDD space.

If anyone has any actual facts about this, please do share though.